# JQuery functions not running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The program below contains various error messages to be displayed under certain conditions. These conditions are found through PHP code, after which the necessary JQuery script is echoed in PHP to make the messages appear.

At first, all messages in the .warning class are hidden. Then, if a certain condition is met, particular ids of this class are shown. Below is the relevant code.

```
<?php require_once 'connection.php'; ?>
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Create Account</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles2.css">
        <script src="JQuery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

 $('.warning').hide();

 });


    </script>

    <div class="unloggedheadingbar">

    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="createaccount">  

        <center><h1>Create Account</h1></center>

    <center><table>
        <form action="create_account.php" method="post">

         <tr><td><font class="createaccountfont">Email</font></td><td><input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="someone@somewhere.com" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Create'])){ echo $_POST['Email']; } ?>" class="createaccounttext"></td></tr>
         <tr><td colspan="2"><br></td></tr>
         <tr><td><font class="createaccountfont">Password</font></td><td><input type="password" name="Password" class="createaccounttext"></td></tr>
         <tr><td colspan="2"><br></td></tr>
         <tr><td><font class="createaccountfont">Confirm Password&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td><td><input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" class="createaccounttext"></td></tr>

    </table></center>

        <br>

        <center><input type="submit" name="Create" value="Create Account" class="createButton" id="Create"></center>

        </form>

            <br>    

            <div class="warning" id="passwordMatchError">
                <center><font class="warningText">Your password confirmation must match with your original password!</font></center>
            </div>  

            <div class="warning" id="emailFormatError">
                <center><font class="warningText">Your email must match the someone@something.com format.</font></center>
            </div>

            <div class="warning" id="emailDuplicateError">
                <center><font class="warningText">An account under this email already exists.</font></center>
            </div>

        </div>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['Create'])){

        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $password = md5($_POST['Password']);

        if(strpos($email, '@') !== TRUE){

            echo '<script>

                $(".warning").hide();

                $("#emailFormatError").show();

                  </script>';

        }elseif($_POST['Password'] != $_POST['ConfirmPassword']){

            echo '<script>

                $(".warning").hide();

                $("#passwordMatchError").show();

                  </script>';

        }else{

        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE Email = '" . $email . "';";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){

        $query = "INSERT INTO user_table VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $password . "');"; 
        mysqli_query($con, $query);

        }else{

           echo '<script>

                $(".warning").hide();

                $("#emailDuplicateError").show();

                  </script>';

        }

        }
    }

    ?>

</body>
```

However, the objects with particular IDs are not actually shown. Does anyone know why this may be? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery actions should be placed in `$( document ).ready( function () {} );`, i.e.:

```
echo '<script>$( document ).ready( function () {
    $(".warning").hide();
    $("#emailFormatError").show();
} );</script>';
```